# when i want to extract information from query results in django it return none

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-3.x

I want to get the column of result, it prints fine in views, but return nothing in ajax, i don't know why?, there are a same type of function that works fine, but it didn't.

```
def requiredfield(request):
    total_ms=['pratap']
    # #print(T)
    name = ['jay']
    print(name)
    print(total_ms)
    if request.method == "POST":
        datafiles = request.POST.get('datafiles')
        print(datafiles)
        query = 'select id, Must_Have from analytics_fileuploadrequiredata where DataFiles_Name = ' + '"' + datafiles + '"'
        #query = 'select id, Functions from analytics_analyticsreport'
        print(query)
        result = FileUploadRequireData.objects.raw(query)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            ms = result[i].Must_Have
            if ms not in total_ms:
                total_ms.append(ms)
        print(total_ms)
    return JsonResponse(total_ms, safe=False)
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/analytics/requiredfield/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                            datafiles: $("input[name='datafilesname']:checked").val(),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

                            },

                    success : function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert("OK")
}
})
```

Error Shows in cmd when query execute: First line Shows the 'abc' is successfuly append in total_ms.

```
['pratap', 'abc']
[17/Jan/2019 02:23:51] "POST /analytics/requiredfield/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
Not Found: /analytics/assets/img/admin.png
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\asn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[17/Jan/2019 02:23:51] "POST /analytics/requiredfield/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52152)
[17/Jan/2019 02:23:51] "GET /analytics/assets/img/admin.png HTTP/1.1" 404 4604
```

Comment: I'd guess it's the double quotes in your query as most databases don't use those (at least not in the context you are using them in). Also why are you not using django's ORM and why do you build your queries by concatenating strings? This is just asking for sql injections.

Comment: I try with single quote, same thing happen

Comment: How are you getting the list in ajax ?

Comment: what i POST from ajax, problem is in query result., if i don't touch it's okay, alert is working

Comment: Try this: `return JsonResponse ({'list': total_ms})` and in ajax `console.log (data['list']);`

Comment: It's not working

Comment: See When i use result = FileUploadRequireData.objects.raw(query)
            #total_ms.append(result[0].Must_Have), It's fine but when i use   result = FileUploadRequireData.objects.raw(query)
            total_ms.append(result[0].Must_Have), It's not working

Comment: Is `total_ms` displaying correctly inside view with the statement `print (total_ms)` ?

Comment: Yes It's displaying correctly

Comment: Did you verify that your sql query is returning anything outside of your python code?

Comment: No, How Can i do that?

Comment: That depends on the database you use. But you either connect to it from the command line or use some graphical tool and execute your query.

Comment: `print (result)` see if that displays yours columns.

Comment: what print(result) shows:  <RawQuerySet: select id, Must_Have from analytics_fileuploadrequiredata where DataFiles_Name = 'Purchase Register'>

Comment: till query, there is no issue

Comment: If you can't verify that the query itself is correct we can't tell you why it doesn't work in your code. We don't know your database layout nor the contained data. The error might or might not be related, it's impossible to tell since you just silently edited it in without further explanation. Was it throwing that exception the whole time, did it just now occur? Currently the question is very unclear and does not provide enough information for anyone to be able to answer it properly without taking wild guesses.

Comment: @FynnBecker I am using mysql database; Query working on proper way. I want to store query result in variable result. when i start to use variable result like "result[0].Must_Have" and store it to total_ms, it strore into total_ms, print(total_ms) print value but, JsonResponse return none

Comment: @FynnBecker when i try to use cursor=connection.cursor() it return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing issue from backend site, as i mention that every thing prints fine but not return any thing, the problem is in html file file where we mention two times {% csrf_token %"}